# Keyboard Shortcut to hide selected layers in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shortcuts

Similar to Illustrator, is there something like CMD + 3 that would let me hide selected layers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just want to say in Photoshop CC, there is a shortcut assigned to it <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

You can access it if you are already in 'Essentials' workspace.

Comment: CMD + ' toggles the grid view.

Comment: I mentioned cmd + <comma> not <apostrophe>?

Comment: That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: If you correct your answer (change the apostrophe to a comma) I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: Hi Carl, but it is already as a comma. I can remove the quotes around that.

Answer (score 10):

By default there is no option but I know an unused combination is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

You can set it by going to Keyboard Shortcuts

[image]

Then it'll also show up on your menu

[image]

Comment: +1 - May want to add that if Shift+Ctrl+M doesn't appear beside 'Hide Layers' its because it hasn't been set as such in Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts within the layer section. I just had to set mine for this to work.

Comment: @Brian woops my mistake I must've set it and forgot it wasn't a default

Comment: Kudos for knowing it regardless =) I learned something new.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideology behind using that particular key combo aside from its availability?

Comment: Maybe mute? It's preference & availability based. Don't forget to mark as correct =)

Comment: It looks like this shortcut actually is take circa PS CC 2014 by "Active Measurements". May have to suffice with `Shift + CMD + CTRL + M` for future versions.