# How can I quickly hide or delete a layer in Illustrator without using the Layer Panel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I need a way to easily hide/delete a layer in Illustrator. I'm not seeing the command in the shortcuts menu, there has to be a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to hide/delete a layer! I don't want to have to drag my mouse all the way over to click on this tiny eye or garbage can every time I want to toggle a layer on or off. Am I missing the shortcut or is there another option I could be using?

Thanks for your help

Comment: also [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37318/keyboard-shortcut-to-hide-selected-layers-in-photoshop?rq=1) post about photoshop would probably encourage someone new to illustrator that in fact the feature would exist.

Comment: I think the title was the problem so edited it for you. Might still get closed again though if the community thinks so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't find it because it doesn't exist. Your best bet is to record an Action and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.